# Prove that the number of prime numbers is infinite.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that the number of prime numbers is infinite

I want to solve it with this theorem :

For n, a positive integer, and integers i,j with 1≤i<j≤n, we know that gcd ($n!$ $\times$ $i+1$ , $n!$$\times$ $j+1$) $ =1$.

.

The theorem has been proven.But I don't know how to use this theorem to prove my question.

Comment: Relatively prime for infinitely many integers implies it, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642835/how-does-the-fact-that-fermat-primes-are-relatively-prime-imply-there-are-infini) for the argument. So you are done.

Comment: That produces an infinite number of relatively prime numbers. If there were only a finite number of primes you would eventually run out of such pairs.  If $n \ge $ the largest prime you've got then $\gcd(n!+1, n!\cdot 2+1)=1$ but neither are divisible by any of the primes you have so far so there must be more primes somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\gcd(n!+1, n!\times 2 + 1)=1$  but neither $n!+1$ nor $n!\times 2 + 1$ is divisible by any prime less than or equal to $n$.

so there must always be two primes larger than any $n$-- one that divides $n!+1$ and another to divide $n!\times 2 + 1$.

ANd as $n$ is unbounded so are the primes larger than $n$.

.....

But you didn't really need the awkward theorem.

Its enough to point out that $n!+1$ is not divisible by any prime less than or equal to $n$

......

But even that is overkill.  The classic way, the way Euclid did it, is that if you have any finite list of primes, $A$, then $1+\prod_{p\in A}p $ is not divisible by any prime in the list so there must be primes not on the list so no finite list is complete.

Sometimes the classics are best.

Answer (score 1):

Let us use a proof by contradiction. Let us assume $P$ is finite, let $n=\max(P)$, you can see that $n!+1$ is prime. In fact, you can see that each prime number can't divide $n!+1$ (because they divide $n!$, if one would divide $n!+1$, it would divide $n!+1-n!=1$.

So $n!+1$ is prime and $n!+1>n $, so here you have your contradiction